# Ho to pass parameter from orchestrator to activity function

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions

I would like to implement a durable function with such a structure:

```
public static async Task<string> Orchestrator_BatchHandler([OrchestrationTrigger] DurableOrchestrationContext context, [OrchestrationClient] DurableOrchestrationClient starter, ILogger log)
{
    RequestContent requestContent = context.GetInput<RequestContent>();
    ProcessingStatus currentProcessingStatus = ProcessingStatus.NotCompleted;
    int counter = 1;
    while (currentProcessingStatus == ProcessingStatus.NotCompleted)
     {
         context.SetCustomStatus(string.Format(Resources.StartIteration, Counter, requestContent.MaxPartitionsPerBatch));
         currentProcessingStatus = await context.CallSubOrchestratorAsync<ProcessingStatus>(nameof(Orchestrator_Processing), requestContent);
         counter++; // How can I pass this Value to Activity_Processing function?

     }
}
[FunctionName(nameof(Orchestrator_Processing))]
public static async Task<ProcessingStatus> Orchestrator_Processing([OrchestrationTrigger] DurableOrchestrationContext context, [OrchestrationClient] DurableOrchestrationClient starter, ILogger log)
{
  ProcessingStatus processingStatus = await context.CallActivityAsync<ProcessingStatus>(nameof(Activity_Processing), requestContent.MaxPartitionsPerBatch);
}
[FunctionName(nameof(Activity_Processing))]
public static ProcessingStatus Activity_Processing([ActivityTrigger] DurableActivityContext context, ILogger log)
{
   int maxValuePerBatch = context.GetInput<int>();
   StartProcessing(log, maxValuePerBatch);

 }
```

my question is now how can I pass a parameter from first orchestrator `Orchestrator_BatchHandler` to the activity function?
For example `counter` variable in the first orchestrator?

Comment: Did my answer help you? If yes please accept my answer to make this thread clear

Comment: Sorry, but I am looking for another solution, which uses my existing code

Comment: Isn't my solution applicable to your code?

Comment: As you can see, I am using `CallSubOrchestratorAsync` and I dont want to change it to `StartNewAsync`

Comment: Why don't you put counter in second parameter "input" instead of requestContent or put it  both together

Comment: Ok, how can I put both together?

Answer (score 2):

You can use starter.[StartNewAsync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.webjobs.durableorchestrationclient.startnewasync?view=azure-dotnet-legacy&viewFallbackFrom=azure-dotnet-preview) method in your *Orchestrator_BatchHandler* function:

```
    string instanceId = await starter.StartNewAsync("Orchestrator_Processing", someJsonObject);
```

and in your *Orchestrator_Processing* function call [CallActivityAsync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.webjobs.durableorchestrationcontext.callactivityasync?view=azure-dotnet-legacy)

```
        var output = await context.CallActivityAsync<JObject>("Activity_Processing", someJsonObject);
```